# Getting reference to the JavaScript Function object behind an operator

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

Here is a lisp procedure that simply adds 'a' to the absolute value of 'b':

```
(define (a-plus-abs-b a b)
  ((if (> b 0) + -) a b))
```

I think this is beautiful, and I am trying to find the best way of writing this in JavaScript. But my JavaScript code is not beautiful:

```
var plus = function(a,b) {
    return a + b;
};

var minus = function(a,b) {
    return a - b;
};

var aPlusAbsB = function(a,b) {
    return (b > 0 ? plus : minus)(a,b);
}
```

The main problem is that I cannot use the `+` and `-` symbols as references to the functions they really represent as I can with lisp. Can anyone come up with a more graceful way of doing something like this, or have I hit a language boundary?

Obviously, I can do this:

```
var aPlusAbsB = function(a,b) {
    return a + Math.abs(b);
}
```

, but this is more of a thought experiment than a pragmatic question.

Is there any way I can get reference to the core functions in the JavaScript language just as if they were user-defined?

Comment: Have you looked at Functional.js and its quirky-cute syntax for representing simple functions as strings?

Comment: Also I have no idea whether there really are Function instances in any real sense for the built-in arithmetic operators.

Comment: I have seen the Functional library, and it looks cool. I'm just wondering if there is any way to do this using only core JS. And @Pointy I was wondering the same thing. They may not be Function objects, but there is logic there that executes similarly to how a function executes.

Comment: Well I'm interested in the question, academically, but I've never seen any reference that'd make me think there are Function objects like that somewhere. However, Javascript is endlessly surprising.

Comment: @Pointy: I always thought that most arithmetic operators ran at the CPU level.  But that might not be true of JavaScript.

Comment: @Andy E: That would actually make sense, and it would explain why most operators are faster in JavaScript than most other dynamic languages. (This could simply be because of the speed of JavaScript interpreters, though.)

Comment: I can actually make my code a little better: `function aPlusAbsB(a,b) {
    return a + ( b>0 ?  b : -b);
}`

Comment: that's basically `a + Math.abs(b)` .. i like your first approach, although a little longer but is really cool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a very cool idea - would be great for evaluating mathematical expressions but you simply can't set an operator (or the logic behind it) to a variable.  Sorry :-)

Comment: I hate to give you a +1 for the OP's sake, but it's true, there's little you can do about it.

Comment: @musicfreak: lol thanks ;-) I often thought about this because there have been times when I've had to check the state of a variable to decide whether to `+` or `-`, but it would have been so much cooler if I could have just passed the `+` or `-` instead - it would have saved a whole `if` statement!

Comment: Unless proven otherwise by some roving JavaScript maven, this seems like the answer :(.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what aspects of the lisp implementation you find particularly beautiful.  I'll propose another version of your suggestion that I think ends up a little closer to your lisp definition's syntax by doing some dirty things.

```
// Give ourselves + and - functions to level the playing field with lisp.
Number.prototype['+'] = function(x)this+x;
Number.prototype['-'] = function(x)this-x;

// Now we can have some fun.
var aPlusAbsB = function(a,b) a [b > 0 ? '+' : '-'] (b);

// Some other notable language barrier differences, but not too dissimilar?
// (define (a-plus-abs-b a b) ((if (> b 0) + -) a b))
```

Answer (score 3):

Though not as elegant as the LISP code, you could create a function dynamically that acts like an operator (on numbers), but it's not.

```
function op(o) {
    return new Function("a", "b", "return a " + o + " b");
}


function aPlusAbsB(a, b) {
    return (b > 0 ? op('+') : op('-'))(a, b);
}
```

---

Additionally, we can hide the complexity of generating these inside an if wrapper, but that's the closest I can get :)

```
function is(expr, op1, op2) {
    return expr ? op(op1) : op(op2);
}

function aPlusAbsB(a, b) {
    return (is(b > 0, '+', '-')(a, b));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone else got here first, but JS is slightly less purely functional than lisp, operators are not functions or objects, but operators.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more beautiful than your suggestion, though nowhere near as beautiful as your lisp representation of the concept:

```
var aPlusAbsB = function(a, b) {
    var plus = function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    };
    var minus = function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    };
    return (b > 0 ? plus : minus)(a, b);
}
```

This would be equivalent to the following in scheme:

```
(define a-plus-abs-b
  (lambda (a b)
    (let ((plus (lambda (a b) (+ a b))) (minus (lambda (a b) (- a b))))
      (cond ((> b 0) (plus a b))
      (else (minus a b))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's not strictly possible, the closest thing you can do is nest addition and subtraction functions inside.

```
var aPlusAbsB = function(a, b) {
    return (function(a, b) { b > 0 ? a + b : a - b })(a, b);
}
```

Not exactly the same, but it gets the job done in a sufficiently indirect way.